# How do I request a zipfile, extract it, then create pandas dataframes from the csv files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests, python-zipfile

Load in these CSV files from the Sean Lahman's Baseball Database. For this assignment, we will use the 'Salaries.csv' and 'Teams.csv' tables. Read these tables into a pandas DataFrame and show the head of each table.

```
 #Here's the code I have so far:
 import requests
 import io
 import zipfile
 url = 'http://seanlahman.com/files/database/lahman-csv_2014-02-14.zip
 r = requests.get(url,auth=('user','pass'))

 #These were lines of code I looked up but am not sure to use:
 #with zipfile.ZipFile('/path/to/file', 'r') as z:
      #f = z.open('member.csv')
        #table = pd.io.parsers.read_table(f, ...)
 #salariesData = pd.read_csv('Salaries.csv')
 #teamsData = pd.read_csv('Teams.csv')
```

Comment: Questions for homework are generally discouraged here.

Answer (score 3):

Request returns a bytes file, so first convert bytes to zip file:

```
mlz = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
```

To see what's in the zipfile, type:

```
mlz.namelist()
```

Then you can extract and read the CSV corresponding to the index, x:

```
df1  = pd.read_csv(mlz.open(mlz.namelist()[0]))
df2 = pd.read_csv(mlz.open(mlz.namelist()[1]))
```

In your specific case, this will likely be:

```
salariesData = pd.read_csv(mlz.open('Salaries.csv'))
teamsData = pd.read_csv(mlz.open('Teams.csv'))
```

(All of this ^ assumes you're using Python 3.x)